# How to scale html5 canvas to show google maps coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, canvas, scale

I have HTML5 canvas:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="400"
style="border:1px solid #000000; background:#ccc;">
</canvas>
```

and here is easy to draw lines but line must be (x->max 500, y->max400) and thats ok.

But I how I can scale this canvas to show coordinates (latitude, longitude) - coordinates is high precision decimal values:

> {"lat":"52.67554942424349","lng":"8.372654914855957"},{"lat":"52.67528921580262","lng":"8.373513221740723"},{"lat":"52.6759657545252","lng":"8.374114036560059"},{"lat":"52.682574466310314","lng":"8.37256908416748"},{"lat":"52.68356308524067","lng":"8.373942375183105"},{"lat":"52.68293869694087","lng":"8.375487327575684"},{"lat":"52.67685044320001","lng":"8.376259803771973"},{"lat":"52.6756535071859","lng":"8.379607200622559"},{"lat":"52.676017795531436","lng":"8.382096290588379"},{"lat":"52.68101344348877","lng":"8.380722999572754"},{"lat":"52.68351105322329","lng":"8.383641242980957"},

When I draw it on google map then looks like this:
IMAGE URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/haTkH.png

How I can transform my decimal values from coordinates to show this coordinates from above on html5 canvas like on google map? Is there any way? I was spend 3 days to try to find solution for this probem? How that work?

*thanks and sorry for my english*

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  The google maps javascript API v3 uses canvas for some of its rendering.  It sounds to me like you are trying to reproduce that functionality.

Comment: no, as you can see on image http://i.stack.imgur.com/haTkH.png, I can draw line on google map, but now I want to draw the same line with same coordinates on html5 canvas

Comment: External images are not always available...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert google maps polyline to html canvas line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33841982/convert-google-maps-polyline-to-html-canvas-line)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw a lines in google maps, rather than using HTML 5, May be you can considering it using google maps api to draw a line.

if you want more info about how to using it. please read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple).

And, if you want more detail about the API References, please read it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline)...

May be you should try this code snippet below, how to use this services from google maps api.

```js
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-6.1839906,106.82296),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-6.175392,106.827153),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-6.1827,106.82296),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-6.1839906,106.82296),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-6.1860599,106.8217262)];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:400px; width:400px"></div>
```

May be you can precise the line for what you need to...

Comment: no, as you can see on image i.stack.imgur.com/haTkH.png, I can draw line on google map, but now I want to draw the same line with same coordinates on html5 canvas ... so html5 canvas is problem, not google map api, google map is here just as example how need to looks like on canvas