# Convert google maps polyline to html canvas line

Tags: javascript, google-maps, html5-canvas

I need to show a google maps polyline into a html canvas. How I can convert the coordinates like this:

```
lat:25.5643498,lng:45.34492432
```

to canvas coordinates like this?

```
x:230,y:445
```

I tried to "scale" down the coordinates from google but no success.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapCanvasProjection

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scale html5 canvas to show google maps coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892300/how-to-scale-html5-canvas-to-show-google-maps-coordinates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [MapCanvasProjection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapCanvasProjection) method `.fromLatLngToContainerPixel`

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/371y4xps/5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var overlay;
var shapes = [];


function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  overlay.draw = function() {};
  overlay.setMap(map);
  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE
      ]
    }
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
    if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
      if (drawingManager.getDrawingMode()) {
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
      }
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var polyline = event.overlay;
      shapes.push(polyline);
      context.beginPath();
      for (var i = 0; i < polyline.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
        var point = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(polyline.getPath().getAt(i));
        if (i == 0) {
          context.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
        } else {
          context.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
      }
      context.stroke();
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "drawingmode_changed", function() {
    if (drawingManager.getDrawingMode() != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        shapes[i].setMap(null);
      }
      shapes = [];
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#map_canvas {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```